# Scraping images, empty response [scrapy]

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using an example of image scraping with scrapy.

But I don't get any file saved at my computer:

this is the code I'm using:

//Items.py//

```
import scrapy

class ImgurItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

//settings.py//

```
BOT_NAME = 'imgur'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['imgur.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'imgur.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/ubuntu/imgurFront/'
```

//imgur_spider.py//

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from imgur.items import ImgurItem

class ImgurSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'imgur'
    allowed_domains = ['imgur.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.imgur.com']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/gallery/.*']), 'parse_imgur')]

    def parse_imgur(self, response):
        image = ImgurItem()
        image['title'] = response.xpath(\
            "//h2[@id='image-title']/text()").extract()
        rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]
        return image
```

This is the type of response I get:

```
{'image_urls': [u'http:data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'],
 'images': [],
 'title': []}
```

Those are the errors I get:

```
[scrapy] ERROR: File (unknown-error): Error processing file from <GET http://i.imgur.com/BGVbmqM.jpg> referred in <None>




DEBUG: Retrying <GET http:howard-funk.jpg> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused


DEBUG: Scraped from <200
```

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of scrapy you used ?
Be sure you've right to write on folder.

In last case, you can create custom pipelines http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#custom-images-pipeline-example and catch somes errors

Comment: Version 1.0.3  I've try as a root same problem. btw I'm also getting this: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Seems than the website block bot connection. Try to emulate http agent (RandomUserAgentMiddleware on Google) and/or use TOR or proxy with scrapy (HTTP_PROXY on settings.py).

Comment: How can I make sure of that?
In the settings I have:
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'

 if I use scrapy shell I can get scrape the page, except of course for image.

Also using tor seems like overkill, I've try it once but didn't succeed.

Comment: Humm, just see your edit. You try to download image from URL `http:howard-funk.jpg`, so for sure this will not works.

Try to use
`if not 'http:// in rel:
    rel = response.url + '/' + rel`

Somethink like that. Adapt to your spider

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

1. Using `urljoin` is the recommended way to get fully qualified URLs:

   ```
       image['image_urls'] = [response.urljoin(rel[0])]
   ```
2. You are getting base64-encoded images data. You should either skip the values with `data:image` prefix or process them in a different way (because that's the image file content and you don't need to download it).